# Is there any hope to compute the determinant of $56\times 56$ parametric matrix and simplify the result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, simplifying-expressions, coefficients, timing

I have this $56\times 56$ parametric matrix $M$ and I want to compute its determinant where $\{t,y,z\}$ are some real parameters. I use  `Det[M]` but it takes a lot of time without an answer.

**My questions:**

> 1. Is there any hope to calculate this determinant?

> 2. If the answer to the above question is YES, then, I expect the result to be a huge and complicated equation; is it possible to specify all the terms dependent on $y$ and $z$?

```
M:={{-E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, 
  1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, 1 + t, 
  1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1 + t, -1 - t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0}, {E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 
  E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 + t, -1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + t, -1 - t, E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 
  E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + 
   E^((I t)/2) t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + 
   E^((I t)/2) t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 - t, -1 + t, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 
  E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -1 + t, -1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + t, -1 - t, E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 
  E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + 
   E^((I t)/2) t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t,
   E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + 
   E^((I t)/2) t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 - t, -1 + t, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 
  E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -1 + t, -1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + t, -1 - t, E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 
  E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, -E^(((I t)/2)) + 
   E^((I t)/2) t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t,
   E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 - t, -1 + t, E^((I t)/2) + E^((I t)/2) t, 
  E^(-((I t)/2)) - E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)) + E^((I t)/2) t, -E^(-((I t)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 1 + t, 1 - t}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 - t, 1 + t, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + t, -1 - t}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {I t, -I t, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, I t, -I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  I t, -I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  I t, -I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, I t, -I t, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -I t, I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, I t, -I t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I t)/2) + I y), -E^((I t)/2 + I y), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((I t)/2), E^(-((I t)/2)), 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -I E^(-((I t)/2) + I y) t, 
  I E^((I t)/2 + I y) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, I E^((I t)/2) t, -I E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, E^((I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2), E^((I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/
    2 + I z), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  I E^((I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 0, 
  0, -I E^(-((I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/7) + (
    I t)/2 + I z), 0, 0, E^((2 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2), 
  E^((2 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -I E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 
  I E^((2 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((2 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((3 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2),
   E^((3 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 
  0, -E^(-((3 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((3 I \[Pi])/7) + (
    I t)/2 + I z), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  I E^((3 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((3 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 
  0, 0, -I E^(-((3 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((3 I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/7) + (
    I t)/2 + I z), 0, 0, E^((4 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2), 
  E^((4 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -I E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 
  I E^((4 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((4 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((5 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2),
   E^((5 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 
  0, -E^(-((5 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((5 I \[Pi])/7) + (
    I t)/2 + I z), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  I E^((5 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((5 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 
  0, 0, -I E^(-((5 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((5 I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((6 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-((6 I \[Pi])/7) + (
    I t)/2 + I z), 0, 0, E^((6 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2), 
  E^((6 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -I E^(-((6 I \[Pi])/7) - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-((6 I \[Pi])/7) + (I t)/2 + I z) t, 0, 0, 
  I E^((6 I \[Pi])/7 + (I t)/2) t, -I E^((6 I \[Pi])/7 - (I t)/2) t, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(((I t)/2)), -E^(-((I t)/2)), 0, 
  0, -E^(-I \[Pi] - (I t)/2 + I z), -E^(-I \[Pi] + (I t)/2 + 
    I z)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I E^((I t)/2) t, I E^(-((I t)/2)) t, 0, 
  0, -I E^(-I \[Pi] - (I t)/2 + I z) t, 
  I E^(-I \[Pi] + (I t)/2 + I z) t}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specify"? Extract? Assign a value to?

Comment: Get a first overview with numerical calculation for diffeent t, which is much faster. `MM[t_, y_, z_] = M;` `(tab = Table[
     Plot3D[Re@Det@MM[t, y, z], {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
      PlotPoints -> 21, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLabel -> t], {t, 0, 2, .073}];) // AbsoluteTiming`   takes about 80 seconds. and `ListAnimate[tab, AnimationRate -> 1/3]`

Comment: @MarcoB I mean in general if I have a large and complicated multivariable function, say, $1+z+2y+y^2+x+\sqrt{x}+4x^5+e^{ix}+e^{z}+\sin x+\cos y+\cot x+...$ and I want to see all the terms dependent on $x$, how I can do this? I know that the `coefficient` may work but only for specific terms not all the dependent terms.